# Warum wird die Präposition »ins« hier genutzt: "Kannst du ins Konzert kommen?"

Tags: word-choice

> Kannst du ins Büro kommen?
>
> Kannst du ins Konzert kommen?

Was würde das bedeuten, wenn ich statt "ins" die Präposition "an" benutzen würde:

> Kannst du ans Konzert kommen?

Würde das bedeuten, dass 1) man bis zum Veranstaltungsort kommt, aber nicht eintritt oder 2) dass man dem Konzert entlang am Rand herum läuft oder 3) das gleiche wie das Original?

Für den zweiten
Fall, würde das "am Konzert" erfordern?

Comment: Es gibt keinerlei Situation im alltäglichen oder auch im weithergeholten Alltag, in der man "Kannst du an das Konzert kommen" sagen würde. Man kann sagen "Kannst du ins Konzert kommen?" oder auch "Kannst du zum Konzert kommen?". Soll der Kommende nicht eintreten, könnte man noch sagen: "Kannst du vor den Konzertsaal kommen?"

Comment: By the way, what is the actual question here?

Comment: @Christian Geiselmann lol. There's not a direct 1 to 1 correlation with English here. If I say "an" + location what would that mean in both the dative and accusative cases? Into a concert makes no sense in English.

Comment: There's your answer. "into a concert" makes no sense in English, "an ein Konzert" makes no sense in German. If the concert takes place in a stadium, you could ask "Kannst Du ans Stadion kommen?" if you want someone to come to the stadium, but not actually enter it, to exchange tickets or pick them up after the concert. So "an" would only work with actual places -- in the case of an office you'd rather say "Kannst Du vors Büro kommen", though.

Comment: I think the confusion is about thinking **an** is the only possible translation for **to**. Much more common is **zu** though: *Kannst du **zum** Konzert kommen?*

Comment: @janka, still confusing though since zum is in dative, which I'm guessing is because it's an event(?) but you still go to it which would require accusative.

Comment: *Zu* **always** go with dative, it's not a dual preposition. The dual prepositions are *an, auf, hinter, neben, in, über, unter, vor, zwischen.* That list is exhaustive.

Comment: @janka, that's right.

Comment: @user135711  -  I somehow got the impression that the basic mistake here is to think at all in terms of "how to translate words like 'to', 'at', 'in', etc. from English to German". This is not a good way of dealing with languages. A better question is: "What are typical German expressions in certain situations?" In German it is just "Kannst du zum Konzert kommen", without regard of how something like this would be expressed in English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Was heißt "am/ans Konzert"?

Der Ausdruck "**ans** Konzert" hat gar keine echte Bedeutung: Das Wort **an** tritt üblicherweise nur bei räumlichen Objekten auf:

> Ich hänge das Bild **an** die Wand.

Ein Konzert ist eine Veranstaltung, nicht ein Gegenstand, daher kann etwas nicht **an** einem Konzert sein.<sup>1</sup>
Der einzige Fall, in dem also "**ans** Konzert"sagen würde, ist, dass im Satz ein Verb vorkommt, dass die Präposition *an* verlangt:

> Er denkt **ans** Konzert.

Das gleiche gilt für "**am** Konzert":

> Dass er so fröhlich ist, liegt **am** Konzert, das er gerade besucht hat.

## Vielleicht "am" für "auf dem"?

Eine mögliche Verwirrung ist, dass **am** umgangssprachlich oft kurz für *auf dem*, nicht für *an dem* verwendet wird:

> (ugs.) Ich sitze **am** Pferd.

Das funktioniert aber nur mit **am**, nicht mit **ans**:<sup>2</sup>

> (ugs., schlecht) Ich setze mich <strike>**ans**</strike> Pferd.

Ob man **auf** oder **in** einer Veranstaltung ist, hängt meines Wissens vom jeweiligen Wort, womöglich auch von der Herkunft des Sprechers ab. Für meine Ohren klingt

> Kommst du auch **aufs** Konzert?

mehr nach einem Pop-Konzert, während

> Kommst du auch **ins** Konzert?

mehr nach einem klassischen Konzert klingt, ohne dass ich genauer rechtfertigen könnte, wieso.

<sub>1 In Deutschland, sagt man, glaube ich, "**an** Weihnachten" und "**an** Ostern". Das sind keine Objekte, aber auch keine Veranstaltungen, sondern besondere Tage. Überall sagt man "**am** Montag" oder "**am** Wochenende."</sub>

<sub>2 In meiner (österreichischen) Varietät sagt man umgangssprachlich auch für "an den" "am": "Ich setz mich **am** Sessel."</sub>

Comment: In welcher schönen Landschaft des deutschsprachigen Raums hört man denn einen Satz wie "Ich sitze am Pferd"? Mir fällt dazu eigentlich nur Österreich ein, und selbst da wäre ich nicht sicher... ?

Comment: @Christian Geiselmann In Österreich auf jeden Fall, ich weiß nicht, wie sehr sich das in der Umgangssprache durch Süddeutschland zieht. Wie sagt man im Norden? "aufm Pferd"? "aum Pferd"?

Answer (score 0):

You can regard the sentence

> Kannst Du ins Büro kommen?

as a short form of the equivalent

> Kannst Du in das Büro kommen?

The proposition indicates that at the end of the movement you are **in** the office.